# The action of undoing a layaway

Tags: single-word-requests, sentence

I'm writing a software for a store and I need to put on a report how much money is received when a customer puts an item on layaway, as well as when a customer cancels the layaway and gets the money back.

I just don't know how to name that reversed process of the item being put back to sale. I need a short sentence to make the report understandable.

Example:

```
Layaways: $459.00
Items back to sale from layaway: $239.00 <-- sentence is too long
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about "Canceled Items"?

Comment: 'Canceled items' could also be understood as 'canceled sales'. Maybe 'Canceled layaways' could work. How does it sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Restock" may work. It's short and punchy, and seems to indicate what you mean.

Comment: @JavierRosas If this solved your problem, you can click the green tick on the left to indicate that you accept this answer.

Comment: *Restock* is not completely precise.  If the item was never delivered, but the layaway was canceled, this term fails to capture it.

Comment: +1, but to address Wally’s point that “restock[ing]” might imply that the item has actually left the building, perhaps “**reshelved** [from layaway]” would be clearer.  (cc: @JavierRosas )

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Layaways: $459.00  
Canceled layaways: $239.00
```